# Unable to update firmware on Netgear ReadyNAS Duo V2

Tags: updates, firmware, readynas

I have a Netgear ReadyNAS Duo V2 whose firmware is RAIDiator 5.3.11.

I am trying to update the firmware to RAIDiator 5.3.13 using both the manual upload method and the in-built 'Check for Updates' feature on the said NAS, but in both cases, I keep on getting the 'Unrecognized server error has occurred' message.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the ReadyNas error log, I found that the upgrade failed because the checksum was incorrect when the 5.3.13 firmware was uploaded using Chrome.

I then uploaded manually using Internet Explorer 11, and the upgrade worked fine.